# Expectation of ratio of the shorter to the longer segment

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am struggling with a probability question:

A point is chosen at random on a line segment of length 1. Let X be the ratio of the shorter to the longer segment.

a) Find $\mathbb E$(X)

b) Find P(X < $\frac{1}{4}$)

I was able to solve part b on my own but couldn't solve the first part

what I did in part a:

define probability density function $f$(x) by

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x}{1-x},  & \text{for $x$ < 0.5} \\
\frac{1-x}{x}, & \text{for $x$ > 0.5}
\end{cases}$

then using

$\mathbb E$(X) = $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) dx$,

$\int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{x^2}{1-x} dx$ + $\int_{0.5}^{1}(1-x) dx = 0.1931$

but I get this as wrong answer. Am I approaching in a wrong way?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be the uniform distribution that we use to pick the point.

$$X=\begin{cases}  \frac{U}{1-U} &, U< 0.5 \\ \frac{1-U}{U} &, U \ge 0.5\end{cases}$$

\begin{align}
E[X]&=E[X|U<0.5]P(U<0.5) + E[X|U>0.5]P(U>0.5)\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{0.5} \frac{2u}{1-u} \, du + \frac12\int_{0.5}^1\frac{2(1-u)}{u}\, du \\
&= \int_0^{0.5} \frac{u}{1-u}\, du  + \int_{0.5}^1 \frac{1-u}{u} \, du\\
&= -\int_{1}^{0.5} \frac{1-v}{v}\, dv+ \int_{0.5}^1 \frac{1-u}{u} \, du\\ 
&= 2\int_{0.5}^1 u^{-1}-1\, du \\
&= 2(\ln u-u)|_{0.5}^1\\
&= 2(-1-\ln 0.5+0.5)\\
&= 2(\ln 2-\frac12) \\
&= 2\ln 2 -1
\end{align}

Remark: the $f$ that you stated is not  a pdf.